# How do I create a URL callback function in R?

Tags: r, url, callback, httr

I am trying to get my head around URL callbacks in R. I can send a call to the server's URL using httr::content(GET(..)) In my call I need to give my callback url and then listen for a response back.

How do I create my callback URL?
How do I listen to it?

I have gone through Google and the httr pdf but I think I am getting caught up in nomenclature. Thanks for the help.

I am trying to use this service using R:
[CryptAPI](https://cryptapi.io/docs/#/Callback/callback)

I initiate the call with:

```
data <- httr::content(GET(source_url, query = list(address=address, callback = callback_url)), as = "parsed")
```

But how do I listen to my callback_url?

Comment: What's your code and where does it go wrong?

Comment: I updated my post, hope that helps clarify